# Remove Bg fill from tables in pdf using pymupdf/fitz or pdfminer/pdfplumber

Tags: python, pdf, information-extraction, pymupdf, pdfplumber

I want to remove background fill in cells of table. tired using get_drawings() form fitz, I'm able to change the fill value in drawing object but It reset back to original value before saving the pdf.

```
pdf = fitz.open('input.pdf')
for page_num in range(pdf.page_count):
        page = pdf.load_page(page_num)
        page.insert_text((20,20),'updated')
            # break
        # page._reset_annot_refs()
        shapes = page.get_drawings()
        for shape in shapes:
            # print(shape)
            shape['fill'] = (1.0,1.0,1.0)

pdf.save('output.pdf')
pdf.close()
```

Comment: I think you need to commit the shape to see the update, please read: https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shape.html#Shape.commit

Comment: commit works only when we add a new shape but what I'm trying to do is update already existing shapes value..

Comment: This **_cannot_** work: you are just changing the output of the vector graphics extraction in Python. The PDF page cannot and will not know about this! The only way would be changing the page's appearance source (`/Contents` object(s)) - which requires low-level editing capabilities and a deep knowledge of PDF's syntax for this.

Comment: Any documentation to learn more about pdf ?